# html set width rest of page

Tags: html, css, layout, width

I have an inline-block span that takes up 80% of the page's width, right after that I have another inline-block span, that takes up 0.753em, now I want to make a third one that will take up the rest.

Maybe it'll be clearer in code:

```
<span style="width:80%; display:inline-block; background-color:lime"></span>
<span style="width:0.753em; display:inline-block"></span>
<span style="width:[?????????]; display:inline-block;background-color:lime"></span>
```

The third span, as mentioned should take up the rest of the page's width, what width should I set to it?

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I am concerned it is always 100%. So if you dont specify the width it should take up the rest? Please correct me if I am wrong. Otherwise I suppose that you do not know how many em the 80% are? That would result into a little JS that calculates the width of your elements.

Comment: @Richard and @Dave `inline-block` is made to fit-contents (*unless specified otherwise from the width property*). 100% is for the `block` elements.

Comment: If I don't specify the width, the third span takes up as much width as it needs, and because this span isn't completely filled with text, not specifying the width results in some whitespace. Question is - can this be done without JS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can't think of a way to do it using `display: inline-block`.

Instead, here's a `float`-based solution:

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/82599/)

```
<span style="float:left; width:80%; height:30px; background-color: lime"></span>
<span style="float:left; width:0.753em; height:30px; background-color: green"></span>
<span style="display:block; overflow:hidden; height:30px; background-color:red"></span>
```

Why does this work? http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/#making-room-for-floats

Comment: @thirtydot, my bad, you're right.  In my playing I'd removed the `overflow: hidden` which was key to making it work.  Thanks for following up!

Comment: @SamuelNeff: No problem, it happens. Removing comments.